# Primefaces carousel next() and prev() methods are not working in version 5.3 and 6.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, carousel

I am using Primefaces 5.2 with JSF 2.2. There was not problem with using of primefaces carousel next() and prev() navigation methods until upgrading to new version 5.3 (or 6.0) of primefaces. Is there any idea for the solution of this problem.

Comment: what are the carousel navigation methods? How do you use it? And 'not working' is not detailed enough. Investigate more, use browser developer tools etc...

Comment: Next time please read [ask], and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and [mcve] to show what does not work. And 'not work' could be specified... e.g. "I get a 'not a funtion error when using PF('myWidgetVar').next();"

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. The solution I found was to use the setPage . 
For example:

```
 function CarouselNext()
      {
        var currentPage = PF('wcarouselDistro').page;
        var totalPages = PF('wcarouselDistro').totalPages - 1;
        var c = (currentPage === (totalPages));
        if (!c)
        {
          PF('wcarouselDistro').setPage(currentPage + 1);
        }
      }

   function CarouselPrev()
      {
        var currentPage = PF('wcarouselDistro').page;
        if (currentPage !== 0)
        {
          PF('wcarouselDistro').setPage(currentPage - 1)
        }
      }
```

my components.

```
<p:graphicImage id="s1" library="images" name="prev-icon.png"  
                            style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" onclick="CarouselPrev();" />

 <p:graphicImage id="s7" library="images/ulcs" name="next-icon.png" style="display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;" onclick="CarouselNext();" />
```

I hope to have helped!

Comment: Why is this needed? Do the PF('wcarouselDistro').next() and PF('wcarouselDistro').prev() actually not work in PrimeFaces 5.3  6.0? If so, please file an issue to get it fixed... There is none: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+carousel

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will help me and be enough.

Comment: @Kukeltje 
in my tests , I could not use " next () ; " I'm using Primefaces 6 , will be a bug?

Comment: @Kadir Please advise if it worked in your application? If so , check the answer as the solution to their problem . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. Carousel was redesigned in PF 5.3 (http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3569) and methods were reworked and/or removed.

If you check the Carousel source code in PF 5.2 tag (https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_2/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/carousel/carousel.js) at line 205, next() and prev() methods are there.

But next() and prev() methods were removed from source code. You can check it in PF 6.0 source code: github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/carousel/carousel.js.

For navigation you could use setPage() like Phelipe Galiotti's answer.

I implement next and prev methods for a circular carousel using the code from PF6.0 startAutoplay() method.

```js
function prevImage (PFCarousel) {
  if(PFCarousel.page === 0)
 PFCarousel.setPage(PFCarousel.totalPages - 1);
  else
    PFCarousel.setPage(PFCarousel.page - 1);
}
  
function nextImage (PFCarousel) {
  if(PFCarousel.page === (PFCarousel.totalPages - 1))
    PFCarousel.setPage(0);
  else
    PFCarousel.setPage(PFCarousel.page + 1);
}
```